# Postgres to Oracle Data Migration without third party software

Tags: oracle, postgresql, migration

Need to move data from Postgres DB to Oracle DB via script or hibernate or etc.
Please share best approaches. Seems, Oracle is not supporting this migration directly. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SQL Developer. It also has a [migration assistant](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/migration.htm#RPTUG45388). In addition foreign data wrappers (FDW) might also help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. with that only trying now, but i should do the migration only via Scripts. Because we can't ask the customer to do manually. We need to provide some automatic mechanism to migrate the data from postgres to oracle when they installing our latest versioned application.